# My PATH in my system is not matching the path in the "os" module

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I'm trying to launch Chrome from a python script like this.

```
# Add Chrome to PATH
chromePATH = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application'
os.sys.path.append(chromePATH)

# Open chrome browser
os.system('chrome.exe -remote-debugging-port=9014 --user-data-dir="{}"'.format(profilePath))
```

When I run it I get:

'chrome.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

What I'm guessing is that whatever PATH os.sys.path.append() is modifying isn't the same PATH that is used in os.system()? How do I make sure I'm adding chrome to the right path and that it works when I run the command via os.system()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.system` spawns a subshell that will probably not have the changes to the system path that you made in the python process. If you know the full path to the executable you should pass it to the call

```
os.system('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe -remote-debugging-port=9014 --user-data-dir="{}"'.format(profilePath))
```

Comment: This worked, however I needed to add quotes around the absolute path to chrome since it had spaces. Also, I ended up using os.popen() instead of os.system(). Not sure why, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `os.system`?

```py
os.system('setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"')
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

Adding Chrome to [path variables](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html)

Running with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess

chrome_path = "chrome.exe --new-window"
start_page = "https://google.com"

command = 'cmd /c "%s %s"' % (chrome_path, start_page)
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```